# SQL Issues - The multi-part identifier could not be bound

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm struggling with something that is probably simple. This is through a linked server. I've scanned this forum for clues but I'm still scratching my head. I'm pretty new at this so forgive me for dumb mistakes. Thank you in advance for any clarity you might be able to provide.

Aaron

When I run this query, I have no issues.

```
select i.guid 
from [DBS1].[AltDB].dbo.Item AS i
```

When I run the query below, I get the error. I don't understand how the first query works with `i.guid` and the second does not.

> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 18
>   The multi-part identifier "i.guid" could not be bound.

Query:

```
SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT 
    rrc.Name AS CompName, 'Altiris' AS Source, 
    CASE 
        WHEN i.ProductUninstalled = 1 THEN 'Uninstall ' 
        ELSE '' 
    END + 
    CASE 
        WHEN i.Name = i.Name THEN i.Name 
        ELSE '    - ' + i.Name 
    END AS Summary, 
    eti.ExecutedBy, 
    CASE eti.InstanceStatus 
        WHEN 3 THEN 'Failure' 
        WHEN 0 THEN 'Not Started' 
        WHEN 2 THEN 'Success' 
        WHEN 4 THEN 'Cancelled'
        WHEN 1 THEN 'In Progress' 
        ELSE 'Not Reported' 
    END AS Status, 
    eti.StartTime, 
    eti.EndTime, i.Description AS Detail
FROM
    [DBS1].[AltDB].dbo.Item AS i 
INNER JOIN        
    [DBS1].[AltDB].dbo.ItemVersions AS iv 
INNER JOIN        
    [DBS1].[AltDB].dbo.ItemVersionData AS ivd ON iv.VersionGuid = ivd.VersionGuid ON i.guid = iv.ItemGuid 
INNER JOIN        
    [DBS1].[AltDB].dbo.TaskInstances AS ti ON ivd.VersionGuid = ti.TaskVersionGuid 
INNER JOIN        
    [DBS1].[AltDB].dbo.Evt_Task_Instances AS eti ON ti.ResourceGuid = eti._ResourceGuid AND ti.TaskInstanceGuid = eti.TaskInstanceGuid 
INNER JOIN        
    [DBS1].[AltDB].dbo.RM_ResourceComputer AS rrc ON eti._ResourceGuid = rrc.Guid 
INNER JOIN        
    [DBS1].[AltDB].dbo.TaskInstances AS ti2 ON eti.ParentTaskInstanceGuid = ti2.TaskInstanceGuid 
INNER JOIN        
    [DBS1].[AltDB].dbo.ItemVersions AS iv2 
INNER JOIN        
    [DBS1].[AltDB].dbo.Item ON iv2.ItemGuid = i.guid ON TaskInstances_1.TaskVersionGuid = iv2.VersionGuid
WHERE
    (i.Attributes = 0)
ORDER BY 
    eti.StartTime DESC, eti.EndTime DESC
```

Answer (score 2):

Probably you wanted to use `AND`:

```
[DBS1].[AltDB].dbo.ItemVersionData AS ivd ON iv.VersionGuid = ivd.VersionGuid AND i.guid = iv.ItemGuid INNER JOIN
```

instead of double `ON`:

```
[DBS1].[AltDB].dbo.ItemVersionData AS ivd ON iv.VersionGuid = ivd.VersionGuid ON i.guid = iv.ItemGuid INNER JOIN
```

The same here:

```
[DBS1].[AltDB].dbo.Item ON iv2.ItemGuid = i.guid ON
                  TaskInstances_1.TaskVersionGuid = iv2.VersionGuid
```

**EDIT**:

You've missed `ON` clauses, anyway your code is so unreadable.

Full:

```
SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT 
     rrc.Name AS CompName,
     'Altiris' AS Source, 
     CASE WHEN i.ProductUninstalled = 1 THEN 'Uninstall ' 
          ELSE '' 
     END + 
     CASE WHEN i.Name = i.Name THEN i.Name 
          ELSE '    - ' + i.Name 
     END AS Summary,
     eti.ExecutedBy, 
     CASE eti.InstanceStatus 
        WHEN 3 THEN 'Failure' 
        WHEN 0 THEN 'Not Started' 
        WHEN 2 THEN 'Success' 
        WHEN 4 THEN 'Cancelled'
        WHEN 1 THEN 'In Progress' 
        ELSE 'Not Reported' 
        END AS Status,
    eti.StartTime, 
    eti.EndTime,
    i.Description AS Detail
FROM [DBS1].[AltDB].dbo.Item AS i 
JOIN [DBS1].[AltDB].dbo.ItemVersions AS iv
  ON i.guid = iv.ItemGuid
JOIN [DBS1].[AltDB].dbo.ItemVersionData AS ivd 
  ON iv.VersionGuid = ivd.VersionGuid      
JOIN [DBS1].[AltDB].dbo.TaskInstances AS ti 
  ON ivd.VersionGuid = ti.TaskVersionGuid 
JOIN [DBS1].[AltDB].dbo.Evt_Task_Instances AS eti 
  ON ti.ResourceGuid = eti._ResourceGuid AND 
     ti.TaskInstanceGuid = eti.TaskInstanceGuid 
JOIN [DBS1].[AltDB].dbo.RM_ResourceComputer AS rrc 
  ON eti._ResourceGuid = rrc.Guid
JOIN [DBS1].[AltDB].dbo.TaskInstances AS ti2 
  ON eti.ParentTaskInstanceGuid = ti2.TaskInstanceGuid 
JOIN [DBS1].[AltDB].dbo.ItemVersions AS iv2 
  ON ti.TaskVersionGuid = iv2.VersionGuid
 AND iv2.ItemGuid = i.guid
WHERE i.Attributes = 0
ORDER BY eti.StartTime DESC, eti.EndTime DESC
```

Comment: I don't think that will fix the problem.

Comment: @GordonLinoff See full query there are missed ON clauses

Comment: . . They are not "missed".  See my answer.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Probably you are right, but this code is  messy

Comment: . . If you fix the final reference to `Item`, I think your query will be correct.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably, you want to start the `from` clause like this:

```
FROM [DBS1].[AltDB].dbo.Item i INNER JOIN
     [DBS1].[AltDB].dbo.ItemVersions iv
     ON i.guid = iv.ItemGuid INNER JOIN
     [DBS1].[AltDB].dbo.ItemVersionData ivd
     ON iv.VersionGuid = ivd.VersionGuid INNER JOIN
     . . .
```

Your structure is allowed but ends up being equivalent to this:

```
FROM [DBS1].[AltDB].dbo.Item AS i INNER JOIN
     ([DBS1].[AltDB].dbo.ItemVersions AS iv INNER JOIN
      [DBS1].[AltDB].dbo.ItemVersionData AS ivd
      ON iv.VersionGuid = ivd.VersionGuid
     )
     ON i.guid = iv.ItemGuid INNER JOIN
```

Hmm.  That doesn't explain the problem.  Because this should parse correctly.  But later in the `FROM` clause you do the same thing:

```
 . . .
 eti.ParentTaskInstanceGuid = ti2.TaskInstanceGuid INNER JOIN
 ([DBS1].[AltDB].dbo.ItemVersions AS iv2 INNER JOIN
  [DBS1].[AltDB].dbo.Item
  ON iv2.ItemGuid = i.guid
 )
 ON TaskInstances_1.TaskVersionGuid = iv2.VersionGuid
```

I think this is where your problem is.  Worse, you have a reference to `item` that is not used in the `JOIN`.  You probably intend for an `i2` somewhere in there.

When using joins, you almost never need parentheses.  And all joins should have an `on` clause next to them.

Comment: Thank you both. The issue I posted about is resolved and will fix the other one pointed out.